# How could I get a useful printout of an objc enum from swift code?

Tags: objective-c, swift, language-interoperability

```
    vp.verifyEmail(self.textClaim) {(OYIDCVerificationStatus status)
        in
        println("verifying email \(self.textClaim) returned \(status)")
    }
```

yields "verifying email foo@bar returned (Enum Value)"
(which obviously is of no practical use).
this:

```
    vp.verifyEmail(self.textClaim) {(OYIDCVerificationStatus status)
        in
        var s : CShort = status as CShort //<- this does not compile
        println("verifying email \(self.textClaim) returned \(s)")
    }
```

does not compile

> VerifyEmailViewController.swift:22:21: 'YOIDCVerificationStatus' is not convertible to 'CShort'

even though the enum is declared like so:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(short, YOIDCVerificationStatus) {
    Unavailable = -1,
    ClaimRefuted,
    ClaimVerified
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Would `toRaw` do what you need?

```
 vp.verifyEmail(self.textClaim) {(OYIDCVerificationStatus status)
        in
        println("verifying email \(self.textClaim) returned \(status.toRaw())")
    }
```

Comment: something like toRaw, yes. attempting to do status.toRaw results in VerifyEmailViewController.swift:22:12: 'status' is not a type